# Map write multiple ggplot png files using Purrrr

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I'm trying to use the purrr map function to efficiently write many ggplot images through one call. I wrote example code that's simple for example sake. The approach I took below results in empty png files. It will write and I can open the file but it's all blank. I'm guessing something wrong in the paste0 call? Maybe there's a better way to automate the file name.

```
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.8, 5.7, 5.7, 7, 6.9, 6.8, 7.7, 
7.7, 7.7, 7.9, 7.7), Sepal.Width = c(4, 4.4, 3.8, 3.2, 3.1, 2.8, 
3.8, 2.6, 2.8, 3.8, 3), Petal.Length = c(1.2, 1.5, 1.7, 4.7, 
4.9, 4.8, 6.7, 6.9, 6.7, 6.4, 6.1), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.4, 
0.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 2.2, 2.3, 2, 2, 2.3), Species = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("setosa", 
"versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), class = 
c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), groups = 
structure(list(
Species = structure(1:3, levels = c("setosa", "versicolor", 
"virginica"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 
    4:6, 7:11), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = 
c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))

library(gapminder)

df <- dput(iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  top_n(3, wt = Sepal.Length))


map(.x = c("setosa", "veriscolor", "virginica"),
.f = function(x) {
  foo <- df %>% 
    filter(Sepal.Length == x) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length))+
    geom_histogram()
  
  Cairo(width = 1300, height = 1600, paste0(x," test.", "png"))
  print(foo)
  dev.off()
  
  
})
```

output
[[1]]
null device
1

[[2]]
null device
1

[[3]]
null device
1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of updates required

1. in filter replace the `Sepal.Length == x` with `Species == x`
2. I dont see a function like `Cairo`, replace with `ggsave`
3. when we use ggsave, it will save the plots to default location so check that folder
4. changed the width and height of plots in ggsave

### code

```r
map(.x = c("setosa", "veriscolor", "virginica"),
    .f = function(x) {
      foo <- df %>% 
        filter(Species == x) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length))+
        geom_histogram()
      
      ggsave(width = 14, height = 7, paste0(x," test.", "png"))
      print(foo)
      dev.off()
    })
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

check the default location with `getwd()` and in that location check the saved plots

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues:

- you filter for `Sepal.Length`, but you actually provide the `Species` names, so you have to filter for `Species`
- you've had a typo in versicolor
- if you're only interested in the side effect of a function, use `walk` instead of `map`
- for ggplots, the preferable way to save them is `ggsave`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  top_n(3, wt = Sepal.Length)


walk(.x = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
     .f = function(x) {
       foo <- df %>% 
         filter(Species == x) %>% 
         ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length))+
         geom_histogram()
       
       ggsave(paste0(x," test.", "png"),
              plot = foo,
              width = 1300,
              height = 1600,
              units = "px")
       
     })
```